# How can I detect multi-part form data using PHP?

Tags: php

I tried using:

```
    $this->method = $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

but it returns

`POST`

It is in fact sent using the POST method, but it is multi-part meaning in my case atleast that both

`$_POST` and `$_FILE` are populated.

Thank you.

Comment: shouldn't it read $_FILES?

Comment: I'm not sure of all the ways you can send mutli-part data but I know `$_FILES` is **one** of them.

Comment: @theman It kind of seems like you shouldn't be detecting the type of form data but rather what it contains. Anyway, if you really do want to detect multipart form data you'll find the content type is in `$_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]`.

Comment: For multipart data you'll find it starts with "multipart/form-data".

Comment: Start by reading [The manual for file uploading in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) I am pretty sure you dont need to know if its multipart, all you need to do is test for the existance of `$_FILE`

Comment: I'm using a FormData object on the JS side.

Answer (score -2):

You have to set multipart/form-data when you set up the form. Then when you process the form you look to _POST to get the filename of the upload and _FILES to get the contents of the file. Below is some older code for an app I wrote to handle multipart uploads of .PDF or Word docs. First, check to be sure the filename is set in the _POST, then check that it containes an allowed extension, then check that the extension matches the expected MIME type (a little safer than just allowing anything to upload):

In the form do something like:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Select file to upload:
   <input type="file" name="File" id="fileToUpload">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

Then for processing something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['File'])) {
   if (isset($_FILES['File']['name']['filename'])) {
      if (!$_FILES['File']['error']['filename']) {
         // Check mime type
         $type = $_FILES['File']['type']['filename'];
         if ($type != 'application/pdf' && $type != 'application/msword' &&
                        $type != 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation') {
            echo "<br>Sorry - type: " . $type . " is not supported. ";
            die;
         }
         $fi = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
         //verify file infor matches the mime type;
         $mime = finfo_file($fi, $_FILES['File']['tmp_name']['filename']);
         finfo_close($fi);
         if ($mime != $type) {
            echo "<br>Sorry this file type: " . $type . " does not match the mime type: " . $mime;
            die;
         }
         // Check that the extension is allowed
         $filename = strtolower($_FILES['File']['name']['filename'])
         $whitelist = array('pdf', 'doc', 'pptx');
         $ext = end(explode('.', $filename));
         if (!in_array($ext, $whitelist)) {
             echo '\n<br> Sorry file ' . $filename . ' has invalid extension: ' . $ext;
             die;
         }     
         // If you made it to here  - ok to process file              
      } else {
         // Give back a message for debugging
         switch ($_FILES['File']['error']['filename']) {
             case 1:
                 $errMsg = "UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE - Size " . $img->size . " exceeds php.ini upload_max_filesize";
                 break;
              case 2:
                  $errMsg = "UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE - Size " . $img->size . " exceeds MAX_FILE_SIZE of HTML form";
                  break;
              case 3:
                  $errMsg = "UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL - File did not complete uploading";
                  break;
              case 4:
                  $errMsg = "UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE - File failed to upload";
                  break;
              case 6:
                  $errMsg = "UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR - Missing tmp folder ";
                  break;
              case 7:
                  $errMsg = "UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE - Failed to write file to disk"; 
                  break;
              case 8:
                  $errMsg = "UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION - php extenion stopped this file from uploading - check php.ini";
                  break;
              default:
                  $errMsg = $_FILES['File']['error']['filename'] . " - Unknown error in image upload";
                }
          echo "File Upload died with errors. " . $errMsg;
          die;
     }
}
```

Comment: It's a shame people who disliked this reply didn't specify what was the problem.